# Callout loop not allowed error while calling external service from an apex rest resource - SKUID

Tags: rest-api, callout, skuid

I want to fetch VIN details from an external webservice by callouts, this should be fired from SKUID page once user given input on the required field. From Skuid i am calling apex class which is itself exposed as a web-service in-order to make SKUID to call the service.

But this service is calling another external service to fetch the data, so because of this dual callout's in the same transaction i am getting 'Callout Loop not allowed error'[image]

Is there any workaround to achieve this, i can not make anything as future is because i want the data from callout response to be shown back on SKUID UI.

Comment: I am seeing the same error, although without skuid.  A post comes in, the code calls out to a 3rd party system to get some additional data, and we get a callout loop error.  This link is ambiguous about whether or not the error should only impact callouts to Salesforce services:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/callout-loop-not-allowed-error